# How really work multiples OR's sentence in SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

please I need know how really work OR sentence 
and which of this query are correct....

### For example in the first condition

```
clause.append(" AND (     ( e.isConfidential = false ) ");
```

If it were true, the rest of query sentences never is executed?
How really work in this case?

---

```
clause.append("  OR ( e.coordinatorId = (:userId) )");
clause.append("  OR ( e.status <> 'APPROVED' AND e.status <> 'CLOSED') ");
clause.append("  OR ( e.id IN (SELECT a.meetingId FROM Attendant a where a.userId = (:userId) ) )");
```

---

Query 1.
......

```
clause.append(" AND (     ( e.isConfidential = false ) ");
clause.append("        OR ( e.coordinatorId = (:userId) )");
clause.append("        OR ( e.status <> 'APPROVED' AND e.status <> 'CLOSED') ");
clause.append("        OR ( e.id IN (SELECT a.meetingId FROM Attendant a where a.userId = (:userId) ) )");
clause.append("      )  ");
queryParameters.put("userId", userId);
```

Query 2
......

```
clause.append(" AND (    ( e.isConfidential = false ) ");
clause.append("       OR ( (e.isConfidential = true) AND (e.coordinatorId =  (:userId)) )");
clause.append("       OR ( (e.isConfidential = true) AND (e.coordinatorId <> (:userId)) AND (e.status <> 'APPROVED') AND (e.status <> 'CLOSED')) ");
clause.append("       OR ( (e.isConfidential = true) AND (e.coordinatorId <> (:userId)) AND (e.status  = 'APPROVED') AND (e.status  = 'CLOSED') 
                            AND e.id IN (SELECT a.meetingId FROM Attendant a where a.userId = (:userId) ) )");
clause.append("      )  ");
queryParameters.put("userId", userId);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Oracle SQL, since you have a Boolean value, e.isConfidential, and Oracle does not have the Boolean data type. Other than that, if you have difficulty with AND and OR, you should probably spend a little bit of time studying elementary logic before you jump to SQL; SQL is not "introductory level" and if you find it hard to figure out the combinations of AND and OR, you will feel that SQL is impossible to work with.

Comment: Is this trying to be JPQL or SQL?

Comment: JPQL @NeilStockton

Answer (score 0):

So AND / OR logic works as follows;

```
True AND True = True
True AND False = False
False AND False = False

True OR True = True
True OR False = True
False OR False = False
```

So just resolve each bit section by section;

```
True AND (False OR (True AND (False OR True)))
```

Is the same as;

```
True AND (False OR (True AND True))
```

Is the same as;

```
True AND (False OR True)
```

Is the same as;

```
True AND True
```

Is the same as;

```
True
```

I can't comment on whether the query is correct unless I understand what it's for - but the syntax looks okay on first glance.

Are you getting any error messages on execution?